# Why is this a mutable borrow?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Why is this a mutable borrow? My thinking is calling get_index() is a mutable borrow, but once it returns a shared reference, that's just a shared borrow now. It should be fine to do other shared borrows, but the borrow checker doesn't see it that way. How do I fix this? Keep in mind this is a toy example, in the real code get_index does have good reason to take a &mut self.

```
struct Foo {
    x: i64
}

impl Foo {
    fn get_index(&mut self) -> Option<&i64> {
        if self.x < 0 {
            self.x = 0;
            None
        } else {
            Some(&self.x)
        }
    }
    
    fn use_index(&self, index: &i64) {
        println!("{}", *index);
    }
}

fn main ()
{
    let mut f = Foo{x: 12};
    if let Some(index) = f.get_index() {
        f.use_index(index);    
    }
}
```

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `f` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:24:9
   |
23 |     if let Some(index) = f.get_index() {
   |                          ------------- mutable borrow occurs here
24 |         f.use_index(index);    
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^-----^
   |         |           |
   |         |           mutable borrow later used here
   |         immutable borrow occurs here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0502`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a11588bbb313b8e63e9dcc640c3aa471

Comment: This is unfortunately a [well known limitation of lifetimes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-mismatch.html#limits-of-lifetimes). I presume in the real code `get_index` also doesn't return a `Copy` type?

Comment: To clarify, it is a limitation, but it is absolutely intentional and not a bug. You can get into trouble with things like [`Mutex::get_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html#method.get_mut) if it didn't work like this.

Comment: Thanks @isaactfa, that explains it perfectly. So it's a borrow checker limitation, not something against the rules of rust. Unfortunately the real thing returns a slice, not a Copy type. I can get around this pretty easily (and safely) with unsafe, but how might I change things to work without cheating?

Comment: e.g. using unsafe: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4089c077c128319c9e7fe16b754d096d

Comment: I worked around it by creating a new method that effectively calls use_index at the end of get_index.

Comment: You could separate the actions of setting `self.x = 0` and returning `&self.x` into two separate methods, the first of which takes `&mut self` and the second of which  takes `&self`. Since the first (setting `self.x`) will be over by the time you want to call the second (getting `&self.x`), the borrow checker shouldn't mind.

Comment: @BallpointBen I ran into this elsewhere, and that's how I worked around it. e.g. I returned Range<usize> instead of &[u8] or  &str, and then had another &self method to convert that into the borrowed slice.